# Installing Unity login screen on Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04, login-screen, display-manager, unity-greeter

So I currently have the newest version of Lubuntu installed on my Panasonic Toughbook cf-19, and its processing and productivity speed seems fantastic.  The only thing I would really prefer would be to have a nicer UI when I log in.

I am totally fine with my lxde desktop configuration, but I feel it would be really nice to have the standard Ubuntu login screen when I boot up.

Is there a way to just install the login screen?

Comment: Do you mean to use lightdm instead of LXDM to manage login into Lubuntu? That's a good idea, I use Lubuntu and didn't wonder about it.

Comment: I'm not sure of the dependencies, the desktops are usually tied to the display manager. LightDM has a nice login screen. if you are using Lubuntu, KDM is probably too heavy for your system. I use LightDM with the Mate desktop. looks god with out all the overhead of KDE, but of course there is less "eye candy"

Comment: That's what I wonder, @ravery. Lubuntu is so lightweight and clever that I guess it's not a good idea to insert something that could compromise its stability, even recognizing Lubuntu login layout is not so beautiful.

Comment: it won't compromise stability per se. but a heavy DM and desktop will use more resources. Mate is a light desktop, and LightDM is also light. though probably not as light as what comes with Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: I feel of course it may slow down it a bit on the login, but since it is just to type the username and password, it wouldnt be that big of an alteration that the whole system would lag the crap out.